# Need to Change Selected Database without re-doing all of my formulas

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I use Crystal reports for Raiser's Edge, so my database connection is to an .mdb file rather than a direct database connection. My IT department had me change the location of these .mdb files to a different shared drive. I'm trying to find the easiest way to switch my selected tables over from one .mdb file to another (file names and table names are all identical, the only difference is the location of the file).

Comment: You can change the data-source using Database | Set Location...

Comment: Thanks Craig. That worked. I was going to the database expert instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the data-source using Database | Set Location...

Comment: Actually, this *is* the answer to the question.